# Power series of $\ln\frac{k}{k-1}$

Tags: power-series, taylor-expansion

In "Concrete Mathematics", equation (6.63) says that $\ln\frac{k}{k-1}$ expands to the infinite series:
$$
\ln\frac{k}{k-1}=\frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{3k^3}+\cdots
$$
But I couldn't see why it can expand in such a way.

Comment: write it over with $k = 1/x,$   so that $x = 1/k$ as well.

Comment: $\ln(k/(k-1))=-\ln((k-1)/k)=-\ln(1-1/k)$ Then use the Taylor expansion for $ln$.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the quick comments, somtimes I just couldn't see such fundamental things...

$$
\begin{align}
\ln\frac{k}{k-1} &= -\ln\frac{k-1}{k}  \\
&= - \ln\left({1-\frac{1}{k}}\right) \\
&= -\left(-\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2k^2}-\frac{1}{3k^3} - \cdots\right) \\\\
&= \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{2k^2}+\frac{1}{3k^3} + \cdots
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{k}{k-1}=\frac1{1-\frac1k}$$ and $$\ln\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)=x+\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3+\dots,$$
when $|x|<1.$